# How to use custom header and footer in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I want to add the code of the custom header and footer in my WordPress Website. In my previous theme, there was a section named "parts" in Theme  File Editor which allowed to add the "header.html" and "footer.html" files to be added (as showin in the screenshot).

[image: Screenshot-1]

But my currently active theme doesn't include that section(please refer to the second screenshot).

[image: Screenshot-2]